# Grouping consecutive numbers into ranges in Python 3.2 : New version for set

Tags: python

```
def range_find(pageset,upperlimit=1000):

    pagerangelist=[]

    for page in range(0,upperlimit):

        if page in pageset and previouspage in pageset:pagerangelist[-1].append(page)
        elif page in pageset and not (previouspage in pageset):pagerangelist.append([page])
        else: pass

        previouspage=page

    pagerangestringlist=[]

    for pagerange in pagerangelist:

        pagerangestringlist.append(str(pagerange[0])+('-'+str(pagerange[-1]))*((len(pagerange)-1)>0))


    return(','.join(pagerangestringlist))


print(range_find({1,2,5,7,8,11,19,25,29,30,31,39,40,41,42,43,44,56,57,59,60,70,71,72,100,101,103,104,105}))
```

Comment: (a) Your indentation is wrtong.  (b) You didn't reference the previous version of this question.  (c) You didn't include the output from your test.  (d) You didn't test the `[1, 2, 4, 5, 3]` case which requires merging two partitions.  If you require the input to be sorted, please state that clearly or add `sorted` to assure it.

Comment: @S.Lott, where is the indentation wrong? He's passing in a set so order doesn't matter. Your other points are good.

Comment: Since the indentation is *now* fixed, it's no longer wrong.

Comment: @S.Lott, okay, so it was just that he failed to format the code correctly in his post, not that the indentation in the original code was incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

```
def range_find(pageset,upperlimit=1000):

    pagerangelist=[]

    for page in range(0,upperlimit):
```

There is no reason to include the 0. Why don't you calculate the upperlimit by max(pageset)?

```
        if page in pageset and previouspage in pageset:pagerangelist[-1].append(page)
        elif page in pageset and not (previouspage in pageset):pagerangelist.append([page])
        else: pass
```

Don't squish all that stuff onto one line. It makes it harder to read. Having an else: pass case is useless

```
        previouspage=page
```

Since you are counting, just use page - 1 instead of previouspage

```
    pagerangestringlist=[]

    for pagerange in pagerangelist:

        pagerangestringlist.append(str(pagerange[0])+('-'+str(pagerange[-1]))*((len(pagerange)-1)>0))
```

Too clever. Just use an if. This technique makes it harder to see what is going on. Also pointless extra parens.

```
    return(','.join(pagerangestringlist))
```

Don't put parens around your return statement expressions.

Algorithmwise this may be problematic because it will slower for books with many pages even if you don't use many pages from them. For example

```
range_find({1, 2, 1000000},100000000)
```

Will spend a long time churning through pages that aren't really of interest.